# What is the difference between 'make an experiment' and 'do an experiment'?

Tags: word-choice

I have come across both *make* and *do* with the noun *experiment*.Are there any differences in meaning?

Thanks.

Comment: Refer these links to know the difference between do or make http://www.vocabulary.cl/Intermediate/Do_Make.htm http://www.espressoenglish.net/difference-between-do-and-make-60-collocations/

Answer (score 4):

To perform an action, we use **Do** and to create something, we use **MAKE**

1) Do your homework

2) Do the dishes

3) Do me a favour

4) Do the laundry

5) Do your job.

1) Make a plan

2) Make an observation

3) Make a suggestion

4) Make an observation

5) Make breakfast

> If an experiment is given in any book and you are just checking it in practical, then you can use **"Do the experiment"**.
>
> But, if you have done any research and want to demonstrate it via experiment, then you can use "**Make an experiment"** as your experiment will derive results that you actually want to demonstrate.

E.g: Teacher asked students to **do the experiment** practically in the lab.

E.g: I **made an experiment** to show that water contains oxygen and hydrogen.
Hope this helps!!

Comment: I made an observation that you somehow listed `make an observation` twice.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the proper word would be *perform*. 'Do' would be acceptable as a permutation of 'perform', for more casual usage. Definitely not 'make', though.

Comment: OP wants to know difference between make an experiment and do an experiment. He doesn't ask for the suitable word ...